# How to test File.delete() function in Junit

Tags: java, file, junit

I have one method like below:

```
public final class someTask {
     public void sampleMethod(String filePath) {
         //It is calling Files.delete() method.
         Files.delete(new File(filePath).toPath)
     }
 }
```

When I test above method(for example ValidRecord in that file, Valid file parameter or not etc) test cases, most of the time my test case failed. Please some one can help me how to test for above cases.

To get file I am using below snippet

```
@Mock
File fileMock;

@Rule
ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

PowerMockito.whenNew(File.class).withArguments(VALID_Path).thenReturn(fileMock);
PowerMockito.when(fileMock.exists()).thenReturn(true);
PowerMockito.when(fileMock.isFile()).thenReturn(true);
```

In this, I am not planning to test Files.deplete() method but I am planning test behaviour of my own method. In that process every time I am getting "java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException" exception even I create temporary file.

Please some can provide with example, how to test this.

Comment: `TemporaryFolder`?

Comment: 1. Why are you testing someone else's code? 2. You know you don't have to use mocks - you can create a *real* file, call your method and check that it doesn't exist ;)

Comment: Test your appplication. Don't test the platform. They already do that for you, more powerfully than you can possibly imagine.

Answer (score 4):

One might argue that your approach is wrong by verifying the behaviour through mocking and interactions. I would do the following

- Create a temp file on local file system
- Call the method `sampleMethod`
- Verify that the file doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

A valuable approach to such kinds of question is to go one step back criticize your application design. Ask yourself, whether you have design issues, especially when you feel that testing your code seems to be a bit difficult.

And indeed: **You can/should improve the design of your software!**

Let's start with your class (btw, I changed names to camel-casing):

```
public final class SomeTask {
    public void sampleMethod(String filePath) {
        Files.delete(new File(filePath).toPath);
    }
}
```

I am going to ignore exceptions. Also, somewhere in your code you are using this class:

```
SomeTask task = new SomeTask();
String filePath = ...
task.sampleMethod(filePath);
```

The first thing to realize: In your class `SomeTask` you have a dependency to a delete-a-file functionality. **Make this dependency visible!**

But how do you do that? With an interface:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface FileDeletor {
    void delete(String filePath);
}
```

You now can change your class by adding a field for such a deletor:

```
public final class SomeTask {
    private final FileDeletor deletor;

    public SomeTask(FileDeletor deletor) {
        this.deletor = Objects.requireNonNull(deletor);
    }

    public void sampleMethod(String filePath) {
        deletor.delete(filePath);
    }
}
```

With this approach you delegate the technical doing of a file deletion to another class that now must implement the interface (shown below). This also makes your class more coherent because it now can concentrate on its own feature(s).

We now need a class that implements that interface:

```
public final class DefaultFileDeletor implements FileDeletor {
    @Override
    public void delete(String filePath) {
        Files.delete(new File(filePath).toPath());
    }
}
```

Note, that I am still ignoring exceptions here. Now we must also change the using side:

```
FileDeletor deletor = new DefaultFileDeletor();
SomeTask task = new SomeTask(deletor);
String filePath = ...
task.sampleMethod(filePath);
```

With this approach you can also build up an application via Spring autowiring or similar dependency injection frameworks.

Let us move on to the testing area. If you wish, you can also test your new class `DefaultFileDeletor`. But you know that it only uses a JDK functionality which itself is tested enough. No need to test this simple class.

But how can you now test your class `SampleTask`? First, you need an implementation of the interface just for the purposes of testing:

```
public class FileDeletorForTestPurposes implements FileDeletor {
    private String filePath;
    private boolean deleted;

    @Override
    public void delete(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
        deleted = true;
    }

    public String getFilePath() {
        return filePath;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }
}
```

Now you are able to test your code:

```
FileDeletorForTestPurposes deletor = new FileDeletorForTestPurposes();
SomeTask task = new SomeTask(deletor);
String filePath = ...
task.someMethod(filePath);
assertEquals(filePath, deletor.getFilePath());
assertEquals(true, deletor.isDeleted());
```

You are now also able to simply create a `FileDeletor` mock and use that by expressing expectations on it.

Answer (score 0):

How to test delete files with Files.delete fuction below is the example
Lets say you have one function like below

```
public boolean deleteFilesWithinPath(Path path, int retryCount){
    boolean status=false;
    while (retryCount < 3) {
        try {
            Files.delete(path);
            LOG.info("File  deleted successfully from work Dir");
            status=true;
            break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                LOG.info("File  was not deleted . Retrying ..");
                status=false;
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                retryCount++;
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                status=false;
                LOG.error(e1.getMessage());
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }

    }
    return status;
}
```

Then you can test above function like below with Powermockit or Mockito

```
@Test
public void testdeleteFilesWithinPath() throws Exception{
    File mockFileTemp = temporaryFolder.newFile("test.csv");
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Paths.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Files.class);
    int retrycount=0;
    Path path = mockFileTemp.getAbsoluteFile().toPath();
    boolean status = mftFileDownloadServiceImp.deleteFilesWithinPath(path,retrycount);
    assertTrue(status);
}

@Test
public void testdeleteFilesWithinPathForIOException() throws Exception{
    File mockFile = temporaryFolder.newFile("test.csv");
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Paths.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Files.class);
    Path path = mockFile.getAbsoluteFile().toPath();
    Files.delete(path);
    int retrycount=0;
    try{
        mftFileDownloadServiceImp.deleteFilesWithinPath(path,retrycount);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        assertThat(e).isInstanceOf(IOException.class);
    }
}
```